# How to handle \n in json files in python

Tags: python, json

so I am trying to read a json file like this:

```
{
      "Name": "hello",
      "Source": " import json \n x= 10, .... "
 }
```

the way I am trying to read it by using the json library in python
thus my code looks something like this:

```
import json

input =''' {
      "Name": "python code",
      "Source": " import json \n x= 10, .... "
 }'''

output = json.load(input)

print(output)
```

the problem that source has the invalid character "\n". I don't want to replace \n with \n as this is code will be later run in another program. 
I know that json.JSONDecoder is able to handle \n but I am not sure how to use.

Comment: `\n` is not invalid. It is a line feed.

Comment: but you can't have it like `\n` in a python string, because then it is escaped for python, but not for json. You need to write `\\n` in your string so that it is `\n` in the json.

Comment: This isn't a problem with JSON files at all; it's only a problem with JSON strings embedded in Python source code. And if you want to do that for some reason, use raw strings: `input = r''' {`

Comment: `input` isn't valid json. If you want to copy your json file to a string, try `print(repr(open('test.json').read()))` and use that.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the backslash in the `input` string, so that it will be taken literally.

```
import json

input =''' {
      "Name": "python code",
      "Source": " import json \\n x= 10, .... "
 }'''

output = json.loads(input)
print output
```

Also, you should be using `json.loads` to parse JSON in a string, `json.load` is for getting it from a file.

Note that if you're actually getting the JSON from a file or URL, you don't need to worry about this. Backslash only has special meaning to Python when it's in a string literal in the program, not when it's read from somewhere else.

Comment: Any reason to prefer that vs suggesting that the OP use a raw string when embedding JSON constants as strings (for whatever reason)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't think you can split a raw string over multiple lines like that. He'd need to escape the newlines, and that's no better than having to escape the backslash in `\n`. Of course, there's no need for the JSON to be on multiple lines.

Comment: `r''' ... '''` is absolutely valid syntax for multi-line raw strings.

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize you could combine the two.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can define the string in raw format using `r`:

```
import json

# note the r
input = r''' {  
      "Name": "python code",
      "Source": " import json \n x= 10, .... "
 }'''
# loads (not load) is used to parse a string
output = json.loads(input)

print(output)
```